How to format wrap text (including caption) properly, such that my main text does not overlap my caption
The image shows the output of the script, where the blue highlighted equation overlaps the caption of figure 15.1

I want the highlighted equation to be centered underneath the main section of text, as the blue arrow shows, along with one or two additional lines of text/equations to stay aligned as stated, at which point the text would return to the normal margins/textwidth. I am using the package wrapfig and graphicx as follows:
\subsection*{(a) Total Energy in Terms of the Semimajor Axis}
\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width =0.4\textwidth]{CMHW5SS/Problem15CM2.png}
    \caption{Illustrates the geometric definiton of an ellipse, where $r$ and $r'$ are the radius vectors from the foci to any particular point on the ellipse, $b$ is the semiminor axis, and $\varepsilon$ is the eccentricity. }
\end{wrapfigure}
Using the geometric definition of an ellipse, 
\begin{equation}
    r+r'=2a
\end{equation}
which says the sum of the distances $r$ and $r'$ from the two foci to any point on the ellipse results in a constant. Then, the distance between the two foci is $2a\varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon$ is the eccentricity of the ellipse. When $\varepsilon<1$ and if $\varepsilon=1$, the ellipse assumes a circular form. Utilizing the law of cosines we obtain $r'$ from fig. 15.1
\begin{equation}
    r'=\sqrt{r^2 +(2a\varepsilon)^2 +4ra\varepsilon \cos\theta}
\end{equation}
Substituting $r'$ into eq. 15.1, we have
$$
\sqrt{r^2 +(2a\varepsilon)^2 +2r(2a\varepsilon) \cos\theta}=2a-r
$$
$$
r^2+4(a\varepsilon)^2 +4ra\varepsilon \cos\theta=4a^2-4ar+r^2
$$
$$
ar+ra\varepsilon \cos\theta=a^2-a^2 \varepsilon^2
$$

I have tried adding \\ inside the caption which did not work, I have also tried formatting the figure in a few different ways matching various methods on the internet with no luck (unfortunately I cannot remember the exact code I tried).
Update: I brute forced it with a minipage, I'd still like a better way to accomplish this but it got the job done well enough. 

welcome! please provide code we can compile i.e. make your fragment into a complete example which reproduces the output you show. off-topic: don't use $$ in latex.

The document class is copyrighted and I don't feel comfortable sharing my prof's copyrighted material, but if you copy and paste the above script underneath the most basic overleaf preamble, with the added packages, it outputs the same issue, albeit with significantly less overlap
eg
\documentclass{article} \
\usepackage{graphicx} \
\usepackage{wrapfig} \
\title{this does the same thing} \\
\date{} \\

\begin{document} \\

\maketitle \\

then copy and paste my script, it is more clearly seen if you change '''o.4\textwidth''' to '''0.45\textwidth'''

if you can reproduce with a standard preamble preamble, just use that in your question. don't forget to add whatever packages are required.

Off-topic: You wrote, if $\varepsilon=1$, the ellipse assumes a circular form. Shouldn't that be $\varepsilon=0$?

it absolutely should be, thank you so much!

When math display environments are involved in the text that should be wrapped around the figure (and caption), you need to help LaTeX in determining the correct number of lines, because by rule every display counts as three lines.
In order to make an example, I comment out part of the text preceding the displays and add some text at the end.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' and 'gather*' environments

\counterwithin{figure}{section}   % just for this example
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\hyphenation{geo-met-ric} % don't want ge-ometric ...

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{15} % just for this example

\subsection*{(a) Total energy in terms of the semimajor axis}

\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.4\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{CMHW5SS/Problem15CM2.png}
\caption{Illustrates the geometric definiton of an ellipse, 
  where $r$ and $r'$ are the radius vectors from the foci to 
  any particular point on the ellipse, $b$ is the semiminor 
  axis, and $\varepsilon$ is the eccentricity.}
\label{fig:ellipse}

\end{wrapfigure}

Using the geometric definition of an ellipse, 
\begin{equation} \label{eq:foci}
    r+r'=2a
\end{equation}
which says the sum of the distances $r$ and $r'$ from the two 
foci to any point on the ellipse results in a constant. 
%Then, the distance between the two foci is $2a\varepsilon$, 
%where $\varepsilon$ is the eccentricity of the ellipse when 
%$\varepsilon<1$; if $\varepsilon=1$, the ellipse assumes 
%a circular form. Utilizing the law of cosines, we obtain 
%$r'$ from fig.~\ref{fig:ellipse} as
\begin{equation}
  r'=\sqrt{r^2 +(2a\varepsilon)^2 +4ra\varepsilon \cos\theta}\,.
\end{equation} 
Substituting $r'$ into eq.~\eqref{eq:foci}, we have
\begin{gather*}
\sqrt{r^2 +(2a\varepsilon)^2 +2r(2a\varepsilon) \cos\theta}=2a-r \\
r^2+4(a\varepsilon)^2 +4ra\varepsilon \cos\theta=4a^2-4ar+r^2 \\
ar+ra\varepsilon \cos\theta=a^2-a^2 \varepsilon^2\,.
\end{gather*}
Some more words some more words some more words some more words 
some more words some more words some more words some more words
some more words some more words some more words some more words
some more words some more words some more words some more words
some more words some more words some more words some more words


\end{document}


The height of the wrapfigure is computed as 19 lines, but due to the three line final gather* environment, the number is wrong and we should subtract at least two lines, maybe three.
If I change into \begin{wrapfigure}[17]{L}{0.4\linewidth} the output becomes

With 16, instead, we'd get

which doesn't seem right. I'm afraid that experimenting is needed, if you want a good printout.
In your particular case, with the full text, the final display ends quite lower than the caption:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' and 'gather*' environments

\counterwithin{figure}{section}   % just for this example
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\hyphenation{geo-met-ric} % don't want ge-ometric ...

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{15} % just for this example

\subsection*{(a) Total energy in terms of the semimajor axis}

\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.4\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{CMHW5SS/Problem15CM2.png}
\caption{Illustrates the geometric definiton of an ellipse, 
  where $r$ and $r'$ are the radius vectors from the foci to 
  any particular point on the ellipse, $b$ is the semiminor 
  axis, and $\varepsilon$ is the eccentricity.}
\label{fig:ellipse}

\end{wrapfigure}

Using the geometric definition of an ellipse, 
\begin{equation} \label{eq:foci}
    r+r'=2a
\end{equation}
which says the sum of the distances $r$ and $r'$ from the two 
foci to any point on the ellipse results in a constant. 
Then, the distance between the two foci is $2a\varepsilon$, 
where $\varepsilon$ is the eccentricity of the ellipse when 
$\varepsilon<1$; if $\varepsilon=1$, the ellipse assumes 
a circular form. Utilizing the law of cosines, we obtain 
$r'$ from fig.~\ref{fig:ellipse} as
\begin{equation}
  r'=\sqrt{r^2 +(2a\varepsilon)^2 +4ra\varepsilon \cos\theta}\,.
\end{equation} 
Substituting $r'$ into eq.~\eqref{eq:foci}, we have
\begin{gather*}
\sqrt{r^2 +(2a\varepsilon)^2 +2r(2a\varepsilon) \cos\theta}=2a-r \\
r^2+4(a\varepsilon)^2 +4ra\varepsilon \cos\theta=4a^2-4ar+r^2 \\
ar+ra\varepsilon \cos\theta=a^2-a^2 \varepsilon^2\,.
\end{gather*}
Some more words some more words some more words some more words 
some more words some more words some more words some more words
some more words some more words some more words some more words
some more words some more words some more words some more words
some more words some more words some more words some more words


\end{document}


Of course this also depends on the height of the figure. With the proportions as in the demo here, it might be convenient to move the picture one line down and specify 18 lines:
\begin{wrapfigure}[18]{L}{0.4\linewidth}

\vspace*{\baselineskip}

\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{CMHW5SS/Problem15CM2.png}
\caption{Illustrates the geometric definiton of an ellipse,
  where $r$ and $r'$ are the radius vectors from the foci to
  any particular point on the ellipse, $b$ is the semiminor
  axis, and $\varepsilon$ is the eccentricity.}
\label{fig:ellipse}

\end{wrapfigure}


Warning Wrapping text around figures might seem appealing. Don't abuse it.


it is more clearly seen if you change 0.4\textwidth to 0.45\textwidth.

I think the final three displayed equations really belong in a single align* or gather* environment, instead of in three separate $$ ... $$ constructs. If you make the associated adjustments, the layout turns out to be fine even if you set the width of the wrapfigure environment to 0.4\textwidth -- but not if you choose 0.45\textwidth.
Aside: Please see the posting
Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$ for compelling reasons for not using $$ in a LaTeX document.


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' and 'gather*' environments
\counterwithin{figure}{section}   % just for this example
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\hyphenation{geo-met-ric} % don't want ge-ometric ...

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{15} % just for this example

\subsection*{(a) Total energy in terms of the semimajor axis}

\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.4\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{CMHW5SS/Problem15CM2.png}
\caption{Illustrates the geometric definiton of an ellipse, where $r$ and $r'$ are the radius vectors from the foci to any particular point on the ellipse, $b$ is the semiminor axis, and $\varepsilon$ is the eccentricity.}
\label{fig:ellipse}
\end{wrapfigure}

Using the geometric definition of an ellipse, 
\begin{equation} \label{eq:foci}
    r+r'=2a
\end{equation}
which says the sum of the distances $r$ and $r'$ from the two foci to any point on the ellipse results in a constant. Then, the distance between the two foci is $2a\varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon$ is the eccentricity of the ellipse when $\varepsilon<1$; if $\varepsilon=1$, the ellipse assumes a circular form. Utilizing the law of cosines, we obtain $r'$ from fig.~\ref{fig:ellipse} as
\begin{equation}
    r'=\sqrt{r^2 +(2a\varepsilon)^2 +4ra\varepsilon \cos\theta}\,.
\end{equation} 
Substituting $r'$ into eq.~\eqref{eq:foci}, we have
\begin{gather*}
\sqrt{r^2 +(2a\varepsilon)^2 +2r(2a\varepsilon) \cos\theta}=2a-r \\
r^2+4(a\varepsilon)^2 +4ra\varepsilon \cos\theta=4a^2-4ar+r^2 \\
ar+ra\varepsilon \cos\theta=a^2-a^2 \varepsilon^2\,.
\end{gather*}

\end{document}


Sweet, that looks great! thank you sm!
